# How to edit an input in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, edit

Im at the point where i can focus in the input and modify the text. But when I press enter, the text doesnt change at all. I leave the code behind. I have one to do list and one done list. when i edit the text in the to do list and i press enter, then the modified value appears in my console, but when i send that to do to the done list return the original value/text

```
import React from "react";
import "../list.css";

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      isEditing: false,
      textInput: this.props.value,
    };
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  // handleOnSubmit(event) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  // let aa = this.state.textInput;
  // if (aa !== "") {
  //   this.setState({ items: [...this.props.items, aa] });
  //   console.log(aa);
  // }
  // }

  // componentDidUpdate() {
  //   this.handleOnSubmit();
  // }

  onChange = (event) => {
    // const textInput = this.textInput;
    this.setState({ textInput: event.target.value });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const editingState = true;
    if (!this.state.isEditing) {
      this.setState({ isEditing: editingState });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.title}
        {this.props.items.map((listItem, index) => {
          return (
            <li id="list-item" key={index}>
              <form onSubmit={(event) => this.onEdit(event)}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref={this.textInput}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    this.onChange(event);
                  }}
                  defaultValue={listItem}
                />
              </form>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onAction(listItem)}>
                {this.props.label}
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onDeleteItem(listItem)}>
                Delete
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onSortItem(listItem)}>
                Sort
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.focusTextInput()}>Edit</button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import List from "./components/List";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todoList: [],
    doneList: [],
  };

  addTodo = (value) => {
    if (value !== "") {
      this.setState({ todoList: [...this.state.todoList, value] });
    }
  };

  handleTodo = (value) => {
    const todoList = this.state.todoList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    const doneList = [...this.state.doneList, value];
    this.setState({ todoList, doneList });
  };

  handleDone = (value) => {
    const doneList = this.state.doneList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    const todoList = [...this.state.todoList, value];
    this.setState({ todoList, doneList });
  };

  deleteItem = (value) => {
    const doneList = this.state.doneList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    const todoList = this.state.todoList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    this.setState({ doneList, todoList });
  };

  sortItem = (value) => {
    const todoList = [value].concat(
      this.state.todoList.filter((item) => item !== value)
    );
    this.setState({ todoList });
  };

  editText = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let aa = this.props.textInput;
    if (aa !== "") {
      this.setState({ todoList: [...this.state.todoList, aa] });
      console.log(aa);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Form onSubmit={this.addTodo} />
        <List
          onDeleteItem={this.deleteItem}
          onAction={this.handleTodo}
          items={this.state.todoList}
          onSortItem={this.sortItem}
          onEdit={this.editText}
          title="Todo"
          label="Done"
        />
        <List
          onDeleteItem={this.deleteItem}
          onAction={this.handleDone}
          items={this.state.doneList}
          title="Done"
          label="Todo"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: please post a codesandbox sample project for us to help you better

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-feynman-fvgbw?file=/src/App.js:103-123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems here. You are using wrong `key` property which makes react act weird, and also your method `onAction` is also wrong because you don't pass somehow the new value.

Have a look at this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-bhaskara-kiwpf

```
<li id="list-item" key={listItem}>
```

then

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onAction(listItem, this.state.textInput)}>
```

and

```
handleTodo = (originalValue, newValue) => {
    const todoList = this.state.todoList.filter(
      listValue => listValue !== originalValue
    );

const doneList = [...this.state.doneList, newValue ? newValue : originalValue];
    this.setState({ todoList, doneList });
  };
```

Comment: i dont know who downvoted my answer but please share your thoughts on your action.

Comment: the edit funcion is working perfectly now, but if i add a new item to the todo list and then i pass it to the done list, the text dissapear cause the element is undefined

Comment: @nicovg15 you are correct. see my updated answer. you need to check if newValue has actually a value, meaning that you edited the text, or else, pass the original value.

Comment: i  just figured out that when i click the edit button it doesnt matter which one i select in the list, its always goes to the last item i've added

Comment: yes, that's weird. can you please post a new question? maybe it's sth that i can't find right now or i don't know but i would like to find out the solution. if you post a new question, please share the link here. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Took a quick look at your `codesandbox`, I think the problem is in your `List` component. There you map over the todos and you provide the `index` as a key. I suspect that's the problem.

React uses this keys to optimize rendering. This is how React can quickly figure out what components have changed, been added or removed. When it's a static list, idx is fine because index zero will always point to the same component. But for a fluid list like yours, index zero may not point to the same component which makes things harder to follow. As a best practice though, it's probably always best to use unique keys.

To get it to work I just used the `todo` name, but you should probably figure something else out if users will be able to use the same names for multiple todos.

You can read more about keys here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

@Apostolos

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-bhaskara-kiwpf

Thank you for your answer, however this doesn't appear to solve the ops question. As when i edit, it doesn't do anything... Maybe i'm missing something.

@nicovg15 Here is a working example of editing as per your sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-moser-4emfp?file=/src/components/listItem.jsx

It's best practice to use a new component when mapping data. For example, instead of this

```
{
  this.props.items.map((listItem, index) => {
    return (
      <li id="list-item" key={index}>
        <form onSubmit={(event) => this.onEdit(event)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={this.textInput}
            onChange={(event) => {
              this.onChange(event);
            }}
            defaultValue={listItem}
          />
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onAction(listItem)}>
          {this.props.label}
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onDeleteItem(listItem)}>
          Delete
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onSortItem(listItem)}>Sort</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.focusTextInput()}>Edit</button>
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

do this

```
{
  this.props.items.map((listItem, index) => (
    <li key={index}>
      <ListItem listItem={listItem} {...this.props} />
    </li>
  ));
}
```

This ensures that the item you select will get edited, updated, etc for that one item you select.

Comment: i only made changes to one button to show how it is done. didn;t change the whole project. did you downvote my answer?

Comment: the problem that the user had was that he was not able to copy the altered input text value from one list to the other and vice versa. so i focused on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import List from "./stest";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todoList: ["Test"],
    doneList: [],
  };

  addTodo = (value) => {
    if (value !== "") {
      this.setState({ todoList: [...this.state.todoList, value] });
    }
  };

  handleTodo = (value) => {
    const todoList = this.state.todoList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    const doneList = [...this.state.doneList, value];
    this.setState({ todoList, doneList });
  };

  handleDone = (value) => {
    const doneList = this.state.doneList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    const todoList = [...this.state.todoList, value];
    this.setState({ todoList, doneList });
  };

  deleteItem = (value) => {
    const doneList = this.state.doneList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    const todoList = this.state.todoList.filter(
      (listValue) => listValue !== value
    );
    this.setState({ doneList, todoList });
  };

  sortItem = (value) => {
    const todoList = [value].concat(
      this.state.todoList.filter((item) => item !== value)
    );
    this.setState({ todoList });
  };

  editText = (event, listItem) => {
    console.log(event.target.value, listItem);
    event.preventDefault();
    let aa = event.target.value;
    let remtodo = this.state.todoList.filter((x) => x !== listItem);
    remtodo.push(aa);
    this.setState({ todoList: [...remtodo] });

    console.log(remtodo);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <List
          onDeleteItem={this.deleteItem}
          onAction={this.handleTodo}
          items={this.state.todoList}
          onSortItem={this.sortItem}
          onEdit={this.editText}
          title="Todo"
          label="Done"
        />
        <List
          onDeleteItem={this.deleteItem}
          onAction={this.handleDone}
          items={this.state.doneList}
          title="Done"
          label="Todo"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React from "react";


class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      isEditing: false,
      textInput: this.props.value,
    };
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  // handleOnSubmit(event) {
  // event.preventDefault();
  // let aa = this.state.textInput;
  // if (aa !== "") {
  //   this.setState({ items: [...this.props.items, aa] });
  //   console.log(aa);
  // }
  // }

  // componentDidUpdate() {
  //   this.handleOnSubmit();
  // }

  onChange = (event) => {
    // const textInput = this.textInput;
    this.setState({ textInput: event.target.value });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const editingState = true;
    if (!this.state.isEditing) {
      this.setState({ isEditing: editingState });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.title}
        {this.props.items.map((listItem, index) => {
          return (
            <li id="list-item" key={index}>
              {/* <form onSubmit={(event) => this.onEdit(event)}> */}
                <input
                  type="text"
                  ref={this.textInput}
                  onChange={(event) => {
                    this.props.onEdit(event,listItem)
                  }}
                  defaultValue={listItem}
                />
              {/* </form> */}
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onAction(listItem)}>
                {this.props.label}
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onDeleteItem(listItem)}>
                Delete
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.onSortItem(listItem)}>
                Sort
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => this.focusTextInput()}>Edit</button>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default List;


Edit event has issue. I have changed and tested edit with test value.
```